# JavaScript events, mixed with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, css, dom-events

I have encountered a huge error for an idea I came up with. So I am working on a project, on my main website and we needed to put up a being worked on page, yadayda but I wanted to add the functionality of letting the user send us their email , but after we received that data a pop dialog would show.. But this doesn't work as I would like for it to.

So what I need help with, is actually the PHP and the JavaScript event to make it acknowledge that the message and email was sent, then show the dialog box. Does anyone know how to do this? Or maybe at least how to make a dialog show after a user did something, like entered information rather then just clicking a button? If anyone can help I would ridiculously appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

If you use jQuery, you can make an AJAX call to your serverside script and use the success callback to initiate the dialog on the client side.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.php',
  data: { name: "WeLikeThePandaz", email: "panda@gmail.com" },
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.status == "OK"){
      // Show dialog 
    }else{
      // Let the user know there were errors
      alert(response.error);
    }
  }
},'json');
```

Here is the relevant documentation for using the `$.ajax` method -

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

---

Your server side PHP code in `ajax/test.php` can then decipher the data that was sent and assemble a json object to be returned to the jQuery -

```
<?php
$err= '';
$name = sanitizeString($_POST['name']);
$email = sanitizeString($_POST['email']);
// note the sanitization of the strings before we insert them - always make sure
// to sanitize your data before insertion into your database.

// Insert data into database.
$result = mysql_query('INSERT INTO `user_table` VALUES...');
if (!$result) {
  $status = "FAIL";
  $err = mysql_error();
}else{
  $status = "OK";
} 

echo json_encode(array('error'=>$err,'status'=>$status)); // send the response
exit();

?>
```

Comment: Freaking sweet! I was stuck on if i should use javascript to call the function then just put the php code in the javascript element witch is the div modal, or can i still use a css div as in ajax too?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  You can't put PHP code on the client side.  Your JavaScript makes a call to execute the PHP script and that script will in turn respond to the JavaScript request.  The connection to your HTML is irrelevant at this stage.  Once you have a response from your PHP script, you can tell the JavaScript to update the HTML according to the response that you get - `success` or `error`

Comment: Ok, i think i get the grips of that but what i can't figure out is how to actually display the dialog depending on if the user failed or succeeded, and fyi im using the reveal dialog , so it comes with it's own javascript , so is there a way trigger the dialog after the specific events took place?

Comment: That depends on the dialog you are using.  I'm sure there is a `show()`/`hide()` pair of functions that you can call.  If you want to make sure that the request was successful, you should return that with the JSON as I did with my example - the `status` variable...  I've made an edit to reflect this...

Comment: Oh ok now i'm starting to see what was blurry to me, so should i connect to my database in the 'code'test.php 'code' file or in the page it's self?

Comment: You connect to the database where ever you need to.  I'd assume you want to connect to the DB from your AJAX PHP script and then return the result to the page your user is on.

Comment: :( poo now it's displaying this 'code'{"error":"","status":"FAIL"}

Comment: why don't you update your post with the code you are using - I think we have gone as far as we can with comments =)

Comment: I haven't figured out how to use the 'code'. Stuff yet, i'm new to this site lol, but ok i will figure out how and post what i've got so far

Comment: No problem - check out the [faq] to learn how to format your posts and specifically [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to learn how to format code blocks :)

Comment: im going to attemp using the code blocks with this -->  <pre></pre>